# Python - Mock object not called when trying to mock object attribute

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I'm trying to write unit tests on a class that uses a client as a class attribute. When I replace the client with a Mock, its behavior is correct, but when I call assert_called() on the Mock it gives me an Assertion error:

`AssertionError: Expected 'mock' to have been called.`

Here is the object class:

`

```
class FakeClientClass:

    def __init__(self):

        self.client = None

    def call_client(self):

        return self.client.result
```

`

And here is the test class:

```
class FakeClientClassTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_call_client(self):

        client_object = FakeClientClass()
        client_object.client = Mock()
        client_object.client.result = "123"

        x = client_object.call_client()

        print(x) # outputs 123

        client_object.client.assert_called()
```

If someone would be kind enough to explain what I'm missing here, and the correct way to do it, I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: `client.result` is not a method, that's why you got the error

Comment: @Devon I think you would like to execute a test with the following asser: `client_object.client.call_client.assert_called()`.